# opencv insufficient memory error during Mat init

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying out OpenCV. In my demo, I want to show the camera preview frames as plain black and white. My demo compiles and runs fine (I could see the black and white preview frames) but crashes after running for a few seconds:

```
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 11059200 bytes)
...
cv::Mat::create(int, const int*, int)]
at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:50)
```

my code:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat src = inputFrame.rgba();

    // insufficient memory error here?
    Mat dest = new Mat(src.size(), src.type());

    Imgproc.threshold(src, dest, 30, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
    return dest;
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding this line.

```
 Mat.release()
```

to every `OpenCV` Matrix object at of course locations where each object was no longer needed

Comment: strangely, the hello world app in the android opencv didn't do a release but it didnt have that insufficient memory error. it was only after adding the threshold op that caused the error. in any case, release() does resolve my problem.